# Cannot use classes from static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, static-libraries

I need to import a library in iOS but I can't seem to figure out how.
I have an .A file and an 'include' folder in my finder.
the 'include' folder has a few .h files and nothing else.

I cant seem to initialize the library, I've tried 
Build phases > Link binary with library > add Other 
and added the .a file

Even after adding it I can't seem to initialize or use the classes in that library. (Use of undeclared identifier)

I'm new to iOS and need acute instructions to implement and understand this.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to set the lib header paths: "Build Settings/Header Search Path" to the one of you "include" folder with the .h and also in the flags, add `-lyourLib` if it's `libyourLib.a`

Comment: Sounds like you are getting there (using *Link binary with library* is correct).  You should also have `.h` files with the `.a` file so you can import  the `.h` files and start using the classes contained in the `.a` file.